# Need to add anchoring/docking to legacy MFC dialog application

Tags: mfc

I am working with MFC code that I believe was developed in the early 90's. I've been given the great task of bringing the software into the 21st century, getting it to work on the likes of Windows 7/8. The application targets numerous platforms, of which one is Windows XP. The original software had a fixed window size and looks terrible on certain OS. I have managed to overcome this but sizing the dialog leaves a lot of grey space. I need to incorporate anchors and docking, similar to .NET.

As always, time is limited, so I need quick, "dirty" solutions, until I get time to rewrite the UI layer. The application contains a number of "screens", each following a similar format. Banner at the top, content consisting of copyright, help on the LHS and task buttons on the RHS and a kind of footer control containing "hotkeys".

As a quick fix, I am thinking that resizing the dialog should cause the following.

1. Banner is anchored left and right
2. LHS/RHS content is split say 60/40
3. Footer is as per the banner

This is made more difficult as different controls are used for different target operating systems/platforms. Basically, the OnInitDialog, uses conditional compilation to to add controls, dynamically, depending on the platform.

To implement this I am guessing I need something like the following...

1. Each control "remembers" its bounds
   I expect this to be tricky as no WM_CREATE message for dialog child controls.
   Possibly use OnParentNotify.
2. Sizing the dialog "remembers" its last size and calculates differences in width and height.
   The dialog sends a parent resize message to its immediate children so they can re-calculate layout.

My question, finally, is what is the best way to approach this?
One idea I have...

1. Introduce a new Widget class that extends CWnd and returns anchor details via a virtual method.
2. Create controls such as CBanner, CCopyright, CFooter etc that implement Widget
3. Create a RowWidget for content that sizes LHS and RHS content appropriately.

Now that was hard to put into words!
Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Karl

Answer (score 1):

Actually a very common question and your reasoning is sound, but rather than reinventing the wheel, it might be better to first look at some freely available implementations along the lines you describe.

For example [this CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11538/Resize-Reposition-the-Controls-in-a-Dialog-at-your) does what I think you need.